# Django app wont run after i have created my first app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFXUs.png)This is the code for my first django app . I cant see the app after I run the server . Server cannot the find the app i have created .

```
<URLS.PY/admin>


from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include

urlpatterns = [
path('^admin/', admin.site.urls)``,
path('^casio/', include('casio.urls')),

]
<URLS.PY/app>

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path(r'^$' , views.index, name='index')
]

<views.py/app>

from django.shotcuts import render
from django.hhtp import HttpResponse

def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h2>HEY!</h2>")
```

Comment: You are mixing old-style and new 2.0 style urls. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/

Comment: would you tell me what should I change here ?

Comment: When you open the app are you going to '/' route or '/casio/' route? Because there are no views routed to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

```
path('^admin/'
```

Should be

```
path('admin/'
```

Don’t use `^` with `path()`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

you have `from django.hhtp import HttpResponse`